# Изменение GET параметров без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Перерыл огромное количество литературы. Ответа на нашел.

Есть адрес:

```
http://site.ru/upload.php
```

Требуется сделать без перезагрузки страницы добавление GET параметров. Т.е. при щелчке по элементу строка изменялась бы:

```
http://site.ru/upload.php?param1=8597&param2=9994
```

Страница не должна перезагружаться.

Подскажите хоть в какому направлении искать ответ? Спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно изменение только адресной строки?

Comment: Снизу все верно написали, эта технология называется HTML History API. Устаревшие клиенты можно ридеректить по нужному адресу или реализовывать аналогичную навигацию через значения хэша `(site.ru/#!/upload.php?param1=value&param2=supervalue`).

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так:

```
 window.history.pushState('1', 'Title', '?param1=1&param2=2');
```